# Getting a particular value from different JSON responses in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, decodable

I have a model called College

```
class College : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let id : String
    let iconUrl : String
}
```

And a few college related APIs, each with a slightly different response. 2 examples are

1. GET api/v1/colleges
   response JSON for this API is

   {
   "success": String,
   "colleges": [College]
   }
2. GET api/v1/college/{collegeID}
   response JSON for this API is

   {
   "success": String,
   "college": College
   }

Now, from both the responses I need to get only the college information, the "success" key is not useful to me. My question is, how to get the college information without creating separate response models for each API? Currently I have implemented separate classes for each API response

```
class GetCollegesResponse : Decodable {
    let success : String
    let colleges : [College]
}
 
class GetCollegeResponse : Decodable {
    let success : String
    let college : College
}
```

And I use them in respective API calls like so

```
Alamofire.request(api/v1/colleges ....).responseJSON { response in
    let resp = JSONDecoder().decode(GetCollegesResponse.self, response.data)
    //get colleges from resp.colleges
}
 
Alamofire.request(api/v1/college/\(id) ....).responseJSON { response in
    let resp = JSONDecoder().decode(GetCollegeResponse.self, response.data)
    // get college form resp.college
}
```

Is there a simpler way to get this done?

Comment: What do you want the end result to be, though? Do you want it to always be `[College]` even for a single result? Multiple approaches here depending on what you want to achieve. For example, you can also make it a generic response type, like so: `APIResponse<T: Decodable> { let success: String, let payload: T }`

Comment: No, I would like to have college array for the first one and only a single college object for the other. In the end, my question boils down to, how to get a particular value from within a json response without creating a Model for the whole response? If there is a way to do that, then it doesn't matter if its College or [College], because we can get array of college using [College].self .

Comment: I first wrote an answer, but then realized that the keys in the API response are also different. You actually have rather different responses from the server, where the key could change based on whatever the response is - i.e. it's not only the value type that's different. So, what determines the key?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way to get an internal object in a very simple step like, max 2 - 3 lines of code. My only issue is, for every API response, I have to create a new model, which is unnecessarily increasing the number of files and complexity. But it seems there is no way to do that without fiddling with generics as you mentioned in your answer. What I wanted is something like
1. Somehow extract only the key I want like its done is swiftyJSON 
let collegeEncoded = response["college"]
2. Decode using decoder
let college = JSONDecoder().decode(College.self,collegeEncoded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the right approach is to model the response as a generic type, like something like this:

```
struct APIResponse<T: Decodable> {
   let success: String
   let payload: T
}
```

from which you could extract the payload.

The problem is that the key with the payload changes: it's `college` for a single result and `colleges` for multiple college results.

If you truly *don't care* and just want the payload, we could effectively ignore it and decode any key (other than "success") as an expected type `T`:

```
struct APIResponse<T: Decodable> {
   let success: String
   let payload: T

   // represents any string key
   struct ResponseKey: CodingKey {
      var stringValue: String
      var intValue: Int? = nil

      init(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
      init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
   }

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ResponseKey.self)
      
      let sKey = container.allKeys.first(where: { $0.stringValue == "success" })
      let pKey = container.allKeys.first(where: { $0.stringValue != "success" })

      guard let success = sKey, let payload = pKey else {
         throw DecodingError.keyNotFound(
            ResponseKey(stringValue: "success|any"),
            DecodingError.Context(
               codingPath: container.codingPath, 
               debugDescription: "Expected success and any other key"))
      }

      self.success = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: success)
      self.payload = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: payload)
   }
}
```

Then you could decode based on the expected payload:

```
let resp = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse<[College]>.self, response.data)
let colleges = resp.payload
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to get the value of a particular item from within a json response without creating a model for the whole response. (at least using codable)

First of all the payload sent from the server will be received by us in an encoded form (UTF8). So we have to decode it first before using it and here is where codable comes in to help us decode our data. If you wish to see the raw conversion using string try this method.

```
let dataConvertedToString = String(data: dataReceivedFromServer, encoding: .utf8)
```

If you still prefer getting just the value alone from the JSON response I would suggest you to use SwiftyJSON. It is a cocoapod framework. You can use SwiftyJSON like this.

```
let json = try! JSON(data: dataFromServer)
json["success"].boolValue
json["college"]["name"].stringValue
```

Comment: In the project used swiftyJSON for parsing till now, but I wanted to reduce the dependencies on third party libraries, so I was thinking of switching to Codable for the new APIs.
Got hit with this problem the moment I started.
I guess there is no way around than making models for each response and then extracting the required data.